# Display Form Input as Stylized String - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to take input from a number field and display it somewhere else on the page.

Here is my HTML

```
<input id="dollar" type="text" name="mytextfield2" onkeyup="updateDollarDisplay();">
<div id="dollarValue"></div>
```

and my javascript

```
function convertDigitsToArray(number){
var s = parseInt(number).toString(10).split("").map(Number);
return s;
}

function updateDollarDisplay() {
    var amount = $('#dollar').value;
    var a = convertDigitsToArray(amount);
    console.log(a[0]);
    $('#dollarValue').text(a[0]);

}
```

Running the exact code in a javascript interpreter works fine, it gives me each digit as an element in the array. When I try to do the same through the HTML page it gives me `NaN` each time. Any ideas?

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/7mzo8eb5/2/ I'd like it to show to input in the grayed div on each input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with `var amount = $('#dollar').value;`

`value` is not an attribute, but `val` is a function. Should be: `var amount = $('#dollar').val();`

Comment: I made the adjustment on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7mzo8eb5/2/) but it still isn't working for me.

Comment: This didn't work, but `var amount = $('#dollar').val();` did work, so I marked this answer correct.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that was me being silly. `.val` is indeed the function. Edited